# If T is invertible, prove it is isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

> Let $T : V → W$ be a linear transformation of vector spaces. We say that
>   $T$ is invertible if and only if there exists a map $S : W → V$ such that
>   $S \circ T = 1_W$ and $T \circ S = 1_V$ . Show that $T$ is an isomorphism if and only
>   if $T$ is invertible.

This is the original question. So, I know how to prove the forward direction, I am simply a bit stuck on the backwards direction. So basically, I need to prove that $T$ is an isomorphism if it is invertible. To do this, I know I must prove that T is bijective. To do that, I did the following:

Since T is invertible, we can employ its inverse $T^{-1}$. To see that T is injective, suppose we have $x,y ∈ V$ and assume that $T(x) = T(y)$. Then, x = $I_v(x)$ = $(T^{-1}∘T)(x)$ = $T^{-1}(T(x))$ = $T^{-1}(T(y))$ = $(T^{-1}∘T)(y)$ = $I_vy$ = $y$.

So, by definition, T is injective. To check that T is surjective, suppose $v ∈ W$. Then $T^{-1}(v)$ is a vector in V.

$T(T^{-1}(v))$ = $T∘T^{-1}(v)$ = $I_w(v)$ = $v$.

So, there is an element from $V$, when used as an input to $T$ (namely $T^{-1}(v)$) that produces the desired output, v, and hence, is surjective.

Therefore, since $T$ is bijective, it follows that T is isomorphic. {end of proof}

This is basically my idea but I feel as if it is wrong. If someone could confirm, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the point. But to be fair, the point is easy to miss for a beginner.

An isomorphism of vector spaces is a linear map, which has a two sided inverse **linear** map.

According to your definition, an invertible linear map is a linear map, which has a two sided inverse map.

The subtle point is that being invertible does not automatically imply that the inverse is also linear. This is what you have to show.

As you progress in mathematics, you will find yourself in situations where bijective homomorphisms are not necessarily isomorphisms.

Comment: Ah okay, that does make sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MooS  can u tell me is this correct for proving $T^{-1}$ is invertible. T is linear transformation. Then $T(a+b) = Ta +Tb, a, b \in W$ applying  $T^{-1}$ on both sides twice, we get $ T^{-1}(a+b) =  T^{-1}(a)+T^{-1}(b)$